# Geometry - Construct the segment $x=\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}$, if $a$ and $b$ are given segments.

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I have a difficult geometry problem with constructing segments. The problem is:

Construct the segment $x=\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}$, if $a$ and $b$ are given segments.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What parts of this can you do?  Do you know how to construct the square root of a segment?  What about the product of two segments?

Comment: No, I don't know any of them

Comment: Aren't they covered in your textbook?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: Look at the constructions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number  The beginning may look dense, but if you scroll down you'll see pictures of the constructions

Comment: Thank you! But I'd like to have the problem solved step by step because I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: @SilviaIbrahimi: It's odd that you've been given a task with no instruction on how to complete it. This also makes helping you difficult, since it's not clear what techniques you might be expected to understand. Perhaps you could at least tell us where you got the problem. From a textbook? An online challenge? somewhere else? What grade level is this? This information can help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you. (Plus, the more you can say about a problem, the less it looks like you're just trying to get someone to do your homework for you.)

Comment: Try it.  You have three products to compute, and the article shows you how.  Then you have to add the pieces, and I assume you know how to do that.  Finally, the article tells you how to calculate the square root of the sum.  If you run into trouble, ask another question.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: That problem gave me my mathematics lecturer and it's probably a mathematics scientific master grade. But I'll try it with directions that gave @saulspatz. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

- $x$ is edge length of the triangle with two edges lengths $a,b$ and internal angle $120$ degrees at vertice intersection of the two edges
- from cosines law, length of the third edge verifies $x^2 = a^2 + ab + b^2$
- so you need to construct $120$ degrees angle: how to do that? draw a circle and split into three congruent sectors (with a compass, making a circumscribed hexagon, you can make it easily)
- now draw to two radial segments (lengths a and b) from the center; join the two radial segments endpoints to get a segment length $x$